# Trying to infinitely reference square picturebox collisions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to get this to detect collisions from my thousands of pictureboxes at once. I cant seem to make it work and I just get a 150 timer tick delay and then infinite collisions
BikeB moves every timer tick also xb, yb is the location on Bikeb. I'm basically creating a line.

```
Dim lineb As New PictureBox
    lineb.Size = New Size(24, 24)
    lineb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0)
    lineb.Location = New Drawing.Point(xb, yb)
    lineb.Tag = creatorb
    Controls.Add(liner)
    liner.Name = "liner" + CStr(creatorb)
    creatorb -= 1 

For Each Ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is PictureBox Then
            If Ctrl.Name <> "BikeB" Then
                If Ctrl.Tag < creatorb - 150 Then
                    If BikeB.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Ctrl.Bounds) Then
                        MsgBox("Blue Loses")
                        BikeMove.Enabled = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
Next
```

Comment: You should store the valid control in a list, that way you can remove the TypeIf and the check on Name. I don't know what creatorb does. If you have a lot of picture box, split your screen in sections and only check the control in that section like a Quadtree. One of the rule for speed is to never do the same thing twice.